# Compare a Python list to SQLite table and get difference

Tags: python, sqlite

Is there an SQL query based solution to compare a Python list to an SQLite table and get those items only which are not present in the table yet?

I store items in my SQLite table and as my code runs I would like to store only those items which are new and want to extend my table.

I know that it would be easy to compare the SQL result as a list with my Python list but I don't want to load the query result to memory since my table contains lots of data, furthermore I have more instances of my code running at the same time.

Comment: Do you really need to do the comparison? If the goal is to only insert new items, why not just insert everything with a conflict clause?

Comment: @abarnert The goal is to insert only new records to the table. If you could give me a more specific example I would highly appreciate it.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you can do this… but I don't think you want to. Your goal is to only insert items that are not present in the table, right? So:

```
CREATE TABLE Breakfast (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, dish UNIQUE)
INSERT INTO Breakfast (dish) VALUES ('spam')
INSERT INTO Breakfast (dish) VALUES ('eggs')
```

Now, in Python, open this database, then:

```
>>> breakfast = ['spam', 'eggs', 'baked beans']
>>> db.execute('SELECT * FROM Breakfast').fetchall()
[(1, 'spam'), (2, 'eggs')]
>>> db.executemany('INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Breakfast (dish) VALUES(?)',
                   [[dish] for dish in breakfast])
>>> db.execute('SELECT * FROM Breakfast').fetchall()
[(1, 'spam'), (2, 'eggs'), (5, 'baked beans')]
```

As you can see, it inserted a new row for `'baked beans'`, while leaving the two existing rows untouched because they were already there.

See the [ON CONFLICT](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html) documentation for how conflict clauses work. (Even though `OR IGNORE` isn't spelled with `ON CONFLICT`, it's a conflict clause.)

---

Notice that this requires having a constraint that can trigger the conflict in the first place—in my example, it's that `UNIQUE` on the `dish` column. If you don't have such a constraint, you have to reproduce the same effects manually (e.g., with a horrible, ugly sub-SELECT). But almost always, the right answer is to add the constraint. Your problem statement implicitly assumes that the value is either a key or otherwise unique, or "items that are not present in the table" really wouldn't make any sense, so your data model should reflect that.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time! That's exactly what I was looking for.